# maximum sized static char array for resources?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'd like to use a `static unsigned char` array to compile a .zip file containing resource files (such as icons, ...) into my executable. I've read here on SO, that a static char array can only support an index range of [0..65535], which would limit me to 64k. But I am not certain whether this still holds true with current C++ compilers? As a side note, obviously I won't actually use indices into the array in my program at all, but only use its address.

EXAMPLE of array contents:

```
xxd -i example
unsigned char example[] = {
  0x4c, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x75, 0x78, 0x20, 0x66, 0x78, 0x2d, 0x38, 0x33, 0x32,
  0x30, 0x20, 0x34, 0x2e, 0x39, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x31, 0x2d, 0x31, 0x2d, 0x41,
  0x52, 0x43, 0x48, 0x20, 0x23, 0x31, 0x20, 0x53, 0x4d, 0x50, 0x20, 0x50,
  0x52, 0x45, 0x45, 0x4d, 0x50, 0x54, 0x20, 0x53, 0x75, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x46,
  0x65, 0x62, 0x20, 0x31, 0x39, 0x20, 0x31, 0x33, 0x3a, 0x34, 0x35, 0x3a,
  0x35, 0x32, 0x20, 0x55, 0x54, 0x43, 0x20, 0x32, 0x30, 0x31, 0x37, 0x20,
  0x78, 0x38, 0x36, 0x5f, 0x36, 0x34, 0x20, 0x47, 0x4e, 0x55, 0x2f, 0x4c,
  0x69, 0x6e, 0x75, 0x78, 0x0a
};
unsigned int example_len = 89;
```

Comment: *"I've read somewhere, that a static char array can only support an index range of [0..65535], which would limit me to 64k."* Where did you get that number? Are you talking about string literals? Not every array of `char` with static storage duration is a string literal.

Comment: Here on SO. Yes, hex string literals.

Comment: By `static char array` if you mean arrays for which memory requirement is know at compile time itself then such arrays are allocated at space where memory management is at premium. That is, such arrays are allocated as part of activation Record of the function under which they are defined. Activation Records are stack frames where memory is limited.

Comment: Ok. The C++ standard still *recommends* that compilers support string literals of length *at least* 65535. And that's all it has to say about that. If you want concrete values, check the documentation of the implementations / platforms you want to support.

Comment: @sameerkn I don't think static arrays are allocated on the stack, sure it's not specified, but I'd be very surprised.

Comment: Have given comment w.r.t to context of static array and dynamic array and   not from storage class point of view i.e  `static char arr[];` Any way place of allocation of memory is implementation defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've read here on SO, that a static char array can only support an index range of [0..65535]

There is no such limit imposed by the C++ standard on the dimensions of an array (static or dynamic). You'll find minimum recommended implementation limits in the [implimits] section of the standard. The limit that you are referring to might be

> Characters in a string literal (after concatenation) [65 536]

A string literal indeed is a static array, but this limitation doesn't extend to array declarations.

A limit that does apply:

> Size of an object [262 144].

But of course, these are *minimum* *recommended* limits. An implementation may support larger objects, and I would expect programs (64-bit in particular) to support much larger objects. You can query this limit at compile time with `SIZE_MAX` macro.

Some limit obviously exists because memory is not infinite. And an implementation may choose to limit even tighter than fits in memory. For example on Linux, if you initialize the data within the source (instead of reading a file at runtime) the data will be stored in a .data segment. The size of this segment can be limited by kernel options. You can find the current limit with `ulimit -d`.

If you suspect that your implementation won't provide you with enough space for a large executable, it's probably best to load the file contents at runtime.

Comment: it says "unlimited".

Comment: @user1095108 then you might need quite a large file to reach the limit.

Comment: The idea is to have some limited resources to report to the user an error, if it occurs. You can't rely on the file system to function in case of an error, since  the file system itself may be the source of the error.

Comment: @user1095108 In that case you will want to store the data in the executable by initializing it in the source. As there is no limit on your system, seems like that shouldn't be a problem. I'm curious, from where is the executable loaded into memory if not from the file system? Couldn't the external file be loaded from wherever the executable was loaded from? Also, I'm curious about why you need >64k memory for an error message.

Comment: We live in the age of bloated apps, size concerns should come as no surprise. The app is loaded from the file system, but as you know, this may span over several devices, some of which might be faulty.